# Greatest compatibility rule in ruby

Tags: ruby, dependencies, version, rule

Using `Gem::Dependency.new(nil, rule).match?(nil, version)`, I can check if a version match a compatibility rule.

With `%w<0.1 0.2.1 0.44>.map {|v| Gem::Version.new v}.max.to_s` I can easily find the last version.

I have an array of dependencies and I need to find the greatest, is there a simple way to do it?

`['~1.5', '~1.6'] -> '~1.6'` for example

Answer (score 1):

Just from an array of version strings?

```
['~1.5', '~1.6'].map { |d| d.sub "~", "" }.map(&:to_f).max
```

Comment: It's bad because there is some different compatibility operators and the max fonction use the float no the Symver spec. For example 0.44 > 0.5 and with your answer, 0.5 is greater than 0.44 and this is wrong.

Comment: You would have to split or obtain the version MAJOR, MINOR, and PATCH numbers and compare those.